# How would you implement a functionality like thunderbird's "quick search"?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, search, indexing, complexity-theory

The well-known Mozilla Thunderbird email client has a search bar called "filter these messages". It allows the user to quickly filter messages by displaying only those whose title, sender or recipients contain the words that the user types.

How would you implement such a functionality, given that it has to be as fast as possible even when displaying tons of messages? Should one use a precomputed index or similar data structure? Or simply iterate through the messages?

Comment: Email titles are only a few characters long. Even with tens of thousands of messages, I think a simple iteration through them would be very fast on mainstream hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of open source software is that you can see the source :). You can even view the source code online:

- [View/Search Mozilla source code online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Viewing_and_searching_Mozilla_source_code_online): you can find the [current Thunderbird source](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/)
- [Other ways to get the source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code)
- I think it's called a [quickFilterBar](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/search?string=quickFilterBar)

Be **very** careful and **play nice** when you look at Mozilla's source code! It would be very rude if you violate their licensing.

I would initially start by doing a direct search and if the performance is insufficient, then I'll try to find a way to improve it. If you're really strapped for performance, then maybe try and implementing some of the [data structures used by Google](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html#data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even though I would have been more interested by a discussion of algorithms and data structures than code itself.